# Can't get to load css styles in angular unit testing using jasmine karma

Tags: css, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How can i get to load css styles in unit tests?
I am working with angular 5,and testing using Jasmine and Karma.The css styles dont show up completely.I imported the bootstrap.min.css but only few of the styles load up.I have done so like this ...

```
files: [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "./src/app/core/**/components/**/*.css"
]
```

in the karma.config,

This loads up some of the styles from both the file paths but not completely.Is there anyother means of importing the styles or can i somehow get to load all the styles in to the unit testing browser.

I am not using material hence the below doesnt seem to work.

```
files: [
     { pattern: '../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo- 
       pink.css', watched: true, included: true, served: true },
       ]
```

Thanks in advance for the answers!